# Excel cells do not update automatically

Tags: excel

I am exporting data from a simulation software to an excel file , I run for a specific number of times , each time I run the model data is saved to a specific sheet and I added one sheet (Summary sheet ) to pick value of specific cells from the previous sheets , but the problem is that cells in the last sheet ( Summary sheet ) do not update automatically after exporting to the file .
how that can be solved  ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDQTk.png)

Comment: To be able to help we need more info. Why do you expect the summary sheet to update and what is it referencing (formula?). Also it would be helpful to share your Excel version (Office 365 or prior).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the formula in your "summary-sheet" contain the "newly added data" in "specific-sheet"?

I expect you are adding new rows to "specific-sheet". And the formula in "summary-sheet" looks something like:

```
=sum("specific-sheet"!B:B)
```

If you "just" need an update/refresh (manually), try hitting <kbd>F9</kbd> (this should recalculate the cells).

If you want to do the **refresh automatically** (without keyboard interaction), then I think it could be solved using **VBA**. That should look something like this:

```vb
Range("summary-sheet"!"A1").Select  // possibly: "summary-sheet!A1"
Selection.Calculate
```

Comment: Thank you , will you check my question after i added an  image to it so you may know exactly what's going on there